# flyway: Previous state of database

Tags: oracle, flyway

Using flyway 3.1 with Oracle 11g

We started using in between not from scratch...for example we did release no 10 and 11 with flyway to migrate SQL script and in` order to test some issue want to revert back database to state of 10 is that possible with Flyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to this:
http://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq.html#downgrade
reverting is not possible.

You should use Liquibase instead, if you really want to have a possibility to downgrade.

Comment: Or you can rebuild a new db to v10 and import just the data you need to reproduce the issue. Or make a v12 that undoes the changes.